# 3d sphere using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, 3d

I have been trying to learn creating basic 3d sphere using html5 canvas and I am new to 3d programming. When I googled, I found this incredibly useful [article](https://thoughtstreams.io/jtauber/drawing-a-sphere/?order=asc).You can find working example there.

```
function drawEllipse(ox, oy, oz, or, alpha, beta, gamma, hidden) {
    for (var theta=0; theta <=2 * Math.PI; theta += 0.02) {
        var px = ox + or * Math.cos(theta);
        var py = oy;
        var pz = oz + or * Math.sin(theta);
        var a = transform(px, py, pz, alpha, beta, gamma);
        if (!hidden || a[2] >= 0) {
            drawDot(radius * a[0], radius * a[1]);
        }
    }
}
function drawDot(x, y) {
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}
/* 3d rotation matrix */
function transform(x, y, z, rz, rx, ry) {
    return [
            ((x * Math.sin(rz) - y * Math.cos(rz)) * Math.sin(rx) + z * Math.cos(rx)) * Math.sin(ry) + (x * Math.cos(rz) - y * Math.sin(rz)) * Math.cos(ry),
            (x * Math.sin(rz) - y * Math.cos(rz)) * Math.cos(rx) - z * Math.sin(rx),
            ((x * Math.sin(rz) - y * Math.cos(rz)) * Math.sin(rx) + z * Math.cos(rx)) * Math.cos(ry) - (x * Math.cos(rz) - y * Math.sin(rz)) * Math.sin(ry)
        ]
}
/*latitude circles*/
    for (var latitude = 0; latitude < Math.PI / 2; latitude += Math.PI / 18) {
        drawEllipse(0, Math.sin(latitude), 0,Math.cos(latitude),0, alpha, gamma,true);
        drawEllipse(0, -Math.sin(latitude), 0,Math.cos(latitude),0, alpha, gamma,true);
    }
/*longitude circles*/
    for (var longitude=0 ; longitude < Math.PI; longitude += Math.PI / 18) {
        drawEllipse(0, 0, 0,1,longitude, Math.PI / 2 + alpha, gamma,true);
    } // alpha and gamma are the x and y axis rotation angles
```

But the only problem is the direction of rotation when dragging the mouse on the sphere. Yaw and Pitch direction is not correct. Rotating left to right(yaw) working fine. But rotating top to bottom(pitch) is different. Can anyone please find a solution ?

Comment: Did you try to find the solution?

Comment: yes ,for a whole month....! I cant find it..

Comment: It would be useful to post here your code.